# Why files from pod were added to my coverage report?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I just added `Firebase` pod and run Tests again:

[image]

Why there are firebase files? This is completely different target...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following line in your podfile in post_install

```
config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
```

This will cause setting code coverage for each pod to false, so any of your pods will **NOT** be visible in code coverage of your app.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Set the CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE flag in the build settings in your podfile

Unfortunately, no more changes are accepted for the existing solution, so here is the complete solution with the complete post-install phase code.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
  end
end
```